# SQLAlchemy Returning Parents and Children Based on Filter on Child

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider the following Flask SQLAlchemy models (`User` excluded for brevity):

```
class Broker(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'brokers'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    # relationships
    accounts = relationship("Account", back_populates="broker")

class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    broker_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('brokers.id'))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    alias = Column(String)

    # relationships
    user_id = relationship("User", back_populates="accounts")
    broker = relationship("Broker", back_populates="accounts")
```

My requirement is the following:

- Return the `Broker`s that have related `Account`s where `Account.user_id == user.id`
- For each returned `Broker`, only include the related `Account`s where `Account.user_id == user.id`

Given the following test data

```
brokers
id | name
---------------------
1  | My first broker
2  | My second broker
3  | My third broker

accounts
id | broker_id | user_id | alias
---------------------------------------------
1  | 1         | 1       | My first account
2  | 1         | 1       | My first account
3  | 2         | 1       | My second account
4  | 1         | 2       | My account one
5  | 2         | 2       | My account two
```

A filter for `Account.user_id == 1` should return a list of two `Broker` objects and associated `Account`s:

- `<Broker 1> -> [<Account 1>, <Account 2>]`
- `<Broker 2> -> [<Account 3>]`

I've tried `Broker.query.join(Account).filter(Account.user_id == 1).all()` which returns only `Broker 1` and `Broker 2` as needed. However the returned `Broker` objects include *all* the `Account` objects related to the given `Broker`, disregarding the filter on `Account.user_id`. My requirement for the returned `Broker` object is to only include the associated `Account` objects that match the passed `Account.user_id`.

How do I write such a query?